# Handling HTTP request-response exchange asynchronously in JAX-RS

Tags: java, jax-rs

If I write what I need as propositions:

- A server should be able to read chunk from request body without blocking every time a client writes and flushes that chunk like Servlet 3.1's [ServletInputStream#setReadListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ReadListener.html).
- A server should be able to write and flush chunk multiple times to response body without blocking like Servlet 3.0's [HttpServletRequest#startAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#startAsync()).

With JAX-RS 2.0, I couldn't meet them. For the first one, I couldn't find such support like ReadListener, and for the second one, I found `AsyncResponse` but its API doesn't allow writing chunk multiple times.

Is there any idea or hack to meet them with only JAX-RS API not using implementation-specific features? I tried `ContainerRequestFilter`, `ContainerResponseFilter`, `ReaderInterceptor` and `WriterInterceptor`, but they didn't help.

Comment: Jersey has [ChunkedInput and ChunkedOutput](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html#chunked-output). But that is definitely not standard JAX-RS.

Comment: Yes I tried to extract them from Jersey but failed. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [their mailing list](https://java.net/projects/jax-rs-spec/lists/users/archive/2014-11/message/9):

> There is no support for non-blocking I/O in JAX-RS 2.0. It is one of the features planned for JAX-RS 2.1 in Java EE 8 .At this point, if you're interested in a portable solution, you'd need to build this on top of Servlet 3.1.